# Querying Nested JSON based on 1 term value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have indexed JSON like below format

**JSON:**

```
{"work":[{"organization":"abc", end:"present"},{"organization":"edf", end:"old"}]}
{"work":[{"organization":"edf", end:"present"},{"organization":"abc", end:"old"}]}
```

I want to query records where organization is "abc" and end is "present"

but below query is not working

```
 work.0.organization: "abc" AND work.0.end:"present"
```

No records are matched

if I give query like below

```
 work.organization: "abc" AND work.end:"present"
```

Both the records are matched. Whereas only the first record is what I want

The matched record should be only the below

```
{"work":[{"organization":"abc", end:"present"},{"organization":"edf", end:"old"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [nested_types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/mapping-nested-type.html). First map work as nested type in elastic using following mappings

```
PUT index_name_3
{
  "mappings": {
    "document_type" : {
      "properties": {
        "work" : {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "organization" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "end" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use the following query to do nested filter match and [innerhits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "work",
            "inner_hits": {},
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                            "term": {
                                "work.organization": {
                                    "value": "abc"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "work.end": {
                                    "value": "present"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it not possible to query without changing the mapping

Comment: no you have to change the mappings to use the above query. anyway work is of type nested and should be mapped to nested

Comment: no it is actually mapped as `text`. Thanks for the answer. I will see if there is any way to do with out changing mapping if not I will mark your as the answer. Give me a day time